# Cannot start Docker in Azure Shell

Tags: azure, docker

When in Azure Shell I type the following

```
PS Azure:\> systemctl start docker.service
```

I get the following error message

> Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not
>   connect: No such file or directory (g-io-error-quark, 1) Failed to
>   connect to bus: No such file or directory

How can I resolve it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: @NancyXiong yes I did, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Cloud Shell offers a browser-accessible, pre-configured shell experience for managing Azure resources without the overhead of installing, versioning, and maintaining a machine yourself. You could read the supported features and tools [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/features#tools).

Moreover, you [could not run the docker daemon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/troubleshooting#cannot-run-the-docker-daemon) in the Azure cloud shell since Cloud Shell utilizes a container to host your shell environment, as a result **running the daemon is disallowed**. You could Utilize **docker-machine** to manage Docker containers from a remote Docker host.

Comment: docker-machine has been deprecated.